# "top" style of table element not moving table down to lower position

Tags: css, html-table

I read this thread:  [Element not moving from top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41296405/element-not-moving-from-top) but I'm not sure it relates to what I'm doing.  I have a test page that echoes out report data using PHP from a MYSQL database and the table's tag line of code is:

```
<table border='1'>
```

what I'd like to have is the table to position itself 27 pixels down from the top of the page so it is not in the background underneath the button I've got at the top.  the button's code is:

```
<input type="button" onclick="emptyReport();" id="Button1" name="button" value="Clear Report" 
style="position:absolute;left:1px;top:1px;width:96px;height:25px;font-family:Arial;font-size:13px;z-index:5">
```

what css property do I need to use to do this?  I'm surprised I couldn't find anything on google considering this issue is overly simple.  thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to answer this question since you haven't provided the full HTML.
What I would suggest is to add the following Css to table:

```
    table {
        position: absolute;
        top: 27px;
    }
```

But this will be a shot in the dark without some more context.
Why would you position the table absolute anyway?

Making it relative with a padding-top: 27px would be more logic in my opinion.